# SSDT for VS2017 offline installation steps

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

The link below is the steps i followed for installing an offline installer of vs2017 and I had a hard time catch up in the offline part. (Steps4-6 to be exact).

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/how-to-install-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-2017-offline-internal/ba-p/334020?fbclid=IwAR3AfLcuxdnLL6Sm4SIcSlKOvRzEdESAIUmRqFn2Wphac2_mk129P0pTyiE

I tried to follow the command to run SSDT_Seup but it keeps on downloading through internet and not on my downloaded data files of SSDT

Can someone assists me to solve my problem.. Sorry but i am new to this type of process. I prefer offline because I want to share this resources to others if i succesfully done it.

Answer (score 0):

Perform these tasks from PC which has internet connectivity.

Step 1  : Download the Standalone Installer from this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer

Step 2 : Download the vs_sql.exe

https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_sql.exe

Step 3 : Open CMD prompt in Administrator mode

CD

vs_sql.exe --layout c:\your_vs2017_offline\ --lang en-us

Copy the offline folder to desired machine.

Source : https://medium.com/@gchandra/install-ssdt-vs2017-offline-a46256e5c86d